# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sound.loadAsync')- React Native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a simple audio system in react native and I am trying to debug for many hours.
I've tried from react-native-audio but that is not working it's giving me `RN.Sound>IsAndroid` error, I am using expo cli and its expo-av giving me this `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'sound.loadAsync')` error here is my code:

```js
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
let [sound, setSound] = useState();

useEffect(()=>{
    Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS:false,
        interruptionModeIOS:Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
        playsInSilentModeIOS:true,
        interruptionModeAndroid:Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DUCK_OTHERS,
        shouldDuckAndroid:true,
        staysActiveInBackground:true,
        playThroughEarpieceAndroid:true
    });
})

setSound(new Audio.Sound());

let [status,setStatus] = useState(false);
sound.loadAsync(require('../../Images/we.wav'), status, false);

const listen =async () => {
    sound.playAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because `setState` is an asynchronous function. Therefore, `setSound(new Audio.Sound());` will be run after `sound.loadAsync(require('../../Images/we.wav'), status, false);`, so at that time `sound` would be undefined.

How to fix:

1. Follow [Expo AV documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/audio/) (recommended)
2. If you really want to run your code outside of useEffect, try this:

```js
const _sound = new Audio.Sound();
_sound.loadAsync(require('../../Images/we.wav'), status, false);
setSound(_sound);
```